# mp4 not playing on Google Chrome when it`s on a subdomain

Tags: google-chrome, mp4

I have some issues when playing mp4 files that are located on a subdomain. This is happening just on Google Chrome. On Firefox or other browsers I can play the mp4 files without any problem.

Please test the links below and explain me why this is not working and what should I do to fix it.

working on Google Chrome > http://hostair.net/subdomain/1.mp4

not working on Google Chrome > http://subdomain.hostair.net/1.mp4

Comment: It's working fine for me. What exactly do you see?

Comment: The second link is not playing, it's just showing the player but the play button doesn't work. It`s impossible to work for you, because I already tried on 4 different devices, 3 on Windows and 1 on Mac